# Can java options be passed in tomcat start up command?

Tags: java, tomcat

I am tweaking the JVM for the tomcat server. I know one can use CATALINA_OPTS to pass on java options. However, one downside of that is that I will have to export that environment variable every time I make a change, so I am wondering if there is an easier way. For example, will something like below work?

```
$ catalina.sh start -server -Xmx512M -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to export this variable just run it that way:

```
CATALINA_OPTS='-server -Xmx512M -XX:MaxPermSize' catalina.sh start
```

Very similar to what you posted. The environment variable is visible only to the started process.

Or you can simply define the variable in catalina.sh file.